# Haskell: Failed to load interface for 'Graphics.Gloss'

Tags: haskell, opengl, gloss

Haskell Community.

I am a newbie in Haskell, can only implement simple Haskell functions.

I tried out one Haskell game program that was open source. While running it, GHC gave the following errors:

> HexDame.hs:1:1: error:
>     Failed to load interface for ‘Graphics.Gloss’

```
    Perhaps you meant
    Graphics.GL (from OpenGLRaw-3.1.0.0)
   Graphics.GL.HP (from OpenGLRaw-3.1.0.0)
   Graphics.GL.NV (from OpenGLRaw-3.1.0.0)
   Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

> HexDame.hs:2:1: error:
>      Failed to load interface for ‘Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game’

```
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

> HexDame.hs:3:1: error:
>       Failed to load interface for ‘Graphics.Gloss.Data.Extent’

```
     Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I am unsure whether Gloss is installed or not. I am using GHC on Windows on a proxy network. The 'cabal update' solution is also not working. 
For other information, I had downloaded the entire Haskell package from the website, so I presume it includes all necessary packages, including GLUT.

Please suggest solutions.

Comment: You can (try to) install Gloss via `cabal install gloss`.  N.B. it is usually best to use the glfw backend via `cabal install gloss -fglfw`.

Comment: can you give the specific `cabal` error? If the `cabal` command itself is being found, but `cabal update` is failing, I suspect you need to set the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY`.

Comment: @ja. I don't think he has used Cabal.  He instead used ghc to compile a single-file program that requires gloss.